# ruby on rails, atom

Tags: ruby-on-rails

OS Windows

I added an action to the controller

```
def who_bought
 @product = Product.find(params[:id])
 @latest_order = @product.orders.order(:updated_at).last
 if stale?(@latest_order)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.atom
  end
 end
end
```

Then I created a file who_bougth.atom.builder

Enter in the browser localhost:3000/products/3/who_bought.atom

An error message is displayed

```
        ProductsController#who_bought is missing a template for this request format     and variant. request.formats: ["application/atom+xml"] request.variant: []
```

Comment: your spelling for file who_bougth.atom.builder is incorrect it should be who_bought.atom.builder

Comment: Thanks, i did not see this

Comment: @RazvitOk I have posted this as an answer if you could mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Check your spelling for file who_bougth.atom.builder i.e is incorrect instead it should be who_bought.atom.builder.